# how to hide bundled products from recently viewed products list

Tags: magento-1.8, product, bundle

I use magento 1.8.1 and iam just trying to hide my bundle products from recently viewed products list and iam just new to programming, help me to achieve this.Here is my recently viewed products Template file

```
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
<div class="block block-list block-viewed">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Recently Viewed Products') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ( $_products as $_product ) : ?>
            <li class="clearfix">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgX, $imgY) ?>" data-srcX2="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgX*2, $imgY*2) ?>" width="<?php echo $imgX; ?>" height="<?php echo $imgY; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
                </a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('recently-viewed-items');</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
$queldorei_blocks = Mage::registry('queldorei_blocks');
if ( !$queldorei_blocks ) {
$queldorei_blocks = array();
} else {
    Mage::unregister('queldorei_blocks');
}
$queldorei_blocks['block_viewed'] = ob_get_clean();
Mage::register('queldorei_blocks', $queldorei_blocks);
```

Thanks in advance any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that we can use to check whether the product is bundle or not

```
if ($_product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) { 
      echo 'Bundled'; 
}
```

So you need to use the above code, as your need. For example, if you put this code inside loop,it will not render bundle product view.

```
<?php foreach ( $_products as $_product ) : ?>
if (!$_product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) { 
        <li class="clearfix">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgX, $imgY) ?>" data-srcX2="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgX*2, $imgY*2) ?>" width="<?php echo $imgX; ?>" height="<?php echo $imgY; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
            </a>
            <div class="product-info">
                <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                <a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
            </div>
        </li>
      <?php } ?>
```

So use that condition according to your need in the template file.

**Note:** Do not edit core template files directly

### EDIT

According to my friend @Marius, my answer seems to be incomplete. So this is an attend to present what happens this page really

The method that we are interested here is `$this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()`. If this provide an empty value, that means the template content will not be rendered in frontend. Let us look what this call provide us. Take a look on `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed::_toHtml()` method.

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (!$this->getCount()) {
        return '';
    }
    $this->setRecentlyViewedProducts($this->getItemsCollection());
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

`_toHtml()` is a special method, that will invoke by Magento automatically in order to render the content of that block. Since this method is defined for recent viewed products block, that means this block get automatically rendered during page loading. Here you can see that the method sets a value `recently_view_products` using this call `$this->setRecentlyViewedProducts($this->getItemsCollection());`. This is what we actually obtain in template file. So let us look what `getItemsCollection()` provides. It is defined in `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Abstract` block class. The method shown below

```
public function getItemsCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_collection)) {
        $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();

        $this->_collection = $this->_getModel()
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes);

            if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
                $this->_collection->setCustomerId($this->getCustomerId());
            }

            $this->_collection->excludeProductIds($this->_getModel()->getExcludeProductIds())
                ->addUrlRewrite()
                ->setPageSize($this->getPageSize())
                ->setCurPage(1);

        /* Price data is added to consider item stock status using price index */
        $this->_collection->addPriceData();

        $ids = $this->getProductIds();
        if (empty($ids)) {
            $this->_collection->addIndexFilter();
        } else {
            $this->_collection->addFilterByIds($ids);
        }
        $this->_collection->setAddedAtOrder();
        if ($this-> _useProductIdsOrder && is_array($ids)) {
            $this->_collection->setSortIds($ids);
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
            ->addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection($this->_collection);
    }

    return $this->_collection;
}
```

The important part of this method is this snippet

```
        $this->_collection = $this->_getModel()
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes);
```

This is the collection method used by this method. Further inspection reveals that, the model that get loaded here is `Mage_Reports_Model_Product_Index_Viewed`. Take a look on this Model class. You can see a unique method that is defined there. It is given below.

```
public function getExcludeProductIds()
{
    $productIds = array();

    if (Mage::registry('current_product')) {
        $productIds[] = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
    }
    print_r($productIds);
    return $productIds;
}
```

As the name specifies, this method is use to exclude some product ids. Currently this method only excludes product that is currently viewing by the user. You can also see that, following filtering is applying in `getItemsCollection()` method also.

```
$this->_collection->excludeProductIds($this->_getModel()->getExcludeProductIds())
                ->addUrlRewrite()
                ->setPageSize($this->getPageSize())
                ->setCurPage(1);
```

So this is the perfect place to apply alternation in this case. What we need to do is, we need to fill the array that holds excluding product ids with bundle product ids also.

**What we need to do here**

Thus we need a simple model rewrite in order to achieve the result. Our rewriting model has a `getExcludeProductIds()`  method that should define like this.

```
public function getExcludeProductIds()
{
    $productIds = array();

    //get all collection
    $collection = $this->getCollection();
    foreach ($collection->getItems() as $item) {

        //check for bundle product, if yes add it to excluding id array
        if($item->getTypeId() === Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE ){

            $productIds[] = $item->getId();
        }

    }
    if (Mage::registry('current_product')) {
        $productIds[] = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
    }
    print_r($productIds);
    return $productIds;
}
```

As you can see, along with current product that is viewing by user, the excluding id array (`$productIds`) now holds bundle product ids also. Thats it.

**Note:** Again do not edit core files. You need to rewrite this model class

Comment: Isn't this an expanded version of what JasonS said? See my comment below his answer.

Comment: @programmer_rkt sorry iam new to coding and i couldn't crack the answer,i tried using hide() command any further help please.

Comment: @Marius : Take a look please. Is that judgifying ?

Comment: @megamage : I updated my answer. Please go through it